# how to get remove \ from json response

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

how to get remove \ from path value from responseJson

```
{"records": [{
  "id":"1",
  "title":"React Native",
  "description":"Complete React Native course for advanced",
  "instructor":"john",
  "chapter":"15",
  "assignment":"15",
  "fees":"799",
  "course":"SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4",
  "thumbnail":"158347549716062111655e61eb296f7fd.jpg",
"path":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/coursePHP\/upload\/158347549716062111655e61eb296f7fd.jpg"
}]}
```

this is the json data i am getting
i need the url from the path
    fetchData(){

```
    return fetch('http://192.168.0.104:8080/api/product/displayCourse.php',{ 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 

    })
    .then((response) => response.json() ) 
    .then( (responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: responseJson.records

        });
        //dataurl = JSON.parse(this.responseJson.records.thumbnail);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      })
}
```

Comment: should be: `responseJson.records[0].path` . `records` is an array, and the path value (containing the URL) is in the object in the first entry of that array.

Comment: i get the path value thank you

Comment: but how to remove the  forward lash

Comment: If it's a URL you'll be wanting to remove the backslashes, not the forward slashes! Anyway you didn't ask that originally, but you can just use the string replace function, it's trivial.You could google it yourself in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

here try this.

```
let path = responseJson.records[0].path;
```

to remove forward slash `\`

```
path = path.replace("\\","");
```